# JComboBox with Vector Action Listener

Tags: java, vector, listener, jcombobox

I have a short question about JComboBox.

I use it with an DevaultComboBoxModel filled with an Vector vec.

So when I change elements in the vector and klick on the combobox, it works. It shows the changed elements.

But when I change the current selected element, it doesn't update the new information.

So my question is, how can I build in an action listener, so that my combobox gets updated, when any element in the list changes?

Or is there even an existing event for comboboxes that I can use for this case?

Thanks for help!

(Working with Netbeans)

So what i am doing is run the app, select Dog, Klick button. And after the selection still says Dog.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxModelBeispiel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame meinJFrame = new JFrame();
        meinJFrame.setTitle("JComboBox Beispiel");
        meinJFrame.setSize(300, 100);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("ComboBox");
        panel.add(label);

        Vector vec = new Vector();


        vec.add("Chicken");
        vec.add("Dog");
        vec.add("Cat");


        JComboBox testCombo = new JComboBox(vec);

        JButton button = new JButton("Change Dog to Mouse");

        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                vec.remove(1);
                vec.add(1, "Mouse");
            }
        });


        panel.add(testCombo);
        panel.add(button);
        meinJFrame.add(panel);
        meinJFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you've got your combo box with items ["Chicken", "Fish", "Beef"] in the model and the user  has chosen "Fish".  Now you change the model to ["Ford","Chrysler","Chevy"].  Are you saying the selected item stays as "Fish", but you want to update it to "Chrysler"?

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: @ Kevin Anderson: Yes, thats my problem.

Comment: @ user1803551, I will try to insert code, but sice this is my first time using this site, i hope im not doing it wrong.